# Redis Cluster not promoting Slave to master when master fails

Tags: redis

I am running a 4 node REDIS CLUSTER on a Windows 2012 box.

My set up is 1 Master and 3 Slaves. When I end the Master Service via the Services component, none of my slaves autopromote themselves to master. How do I get the Slaves to recognize a Master is failing and have them promote as soon as they see the failure. Below is my Redis Config. This is the same Config file for all nodes, the only difference is the port is changed for each node

`port 30002
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
appendonly yes
loglevel notice
logfile "log"
syslog-enabled yes
syslog-ident redis
maxmemory 200mb
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl`

***Edit***

What other information do I need to supply to make this easier to help fix.

***Edit 2***

My end game is a redis cluster , I want this Cluster to have 1 master and 3 slaves. The reason why I want a cluster over a setup with 1 Master and 3 slaves is, I want to avoid installing REDIS Sentinel. I want the cluster to promote the slaves to masters and not redis sentinel doing that.

My Install process is as follows

- Create 4 folders (A,B,C,D)
- In each folder copy the REDIS 64 msi for windows
- In folder A,B,C,D put in a config file just like the one above but different ports
- Install redis service using folders A,B,C,D
- Start all services
- Do Redis Meetup for folders A,B,C,D
- Add replication for folder A over to folder B,C,D
- Assign all keys to redis instance on folder A

voila cluster setup with with FOLDER A being the master and B,C,D being slaves of A. Now the only problem is, when A goes down none of the slaves (B,C,D) auto promote.

***EDIT***

redis.conf file of the master

`port 30001
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
appendonly yes
loglevel notice
logfile "log"
syslog-enabled yes
syslog-ident redis
maxmemory 200mb
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl`

ouput of cluster nodes before i run `sc stop redismasteralpha`

```
05a73c800cccfd8b11d33232887570c52a326afe 10.144.62.3:30002 slave 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 0 1478637832268 5 connected
20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 10.144.62.3:30001 master - 0 1478637837736 5 connected 0-16383
d60d3d0a9f12ef37c997fe44389996d8c7f19c2c 10.144.62.3:30000 myself,slave 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 0 0 1 connected
fda22db5ed5d25e2a8fba82122b47818fba248ce 10.144.62.3:30003 slave 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 0 1478637836644 5 connected
```

after stopping the service

```
05a73c800cccfd8b11d33232887570c52a326afe 10.144.62.3:30002 myself,slave 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 0 0 3 connected
d60d3d0a9f12ef37c997fe44389996d8c7f19c2c 10.144.62.3:30000 slave,fail 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 1478637948956 1478637947808 5 disconnected
fda22db5ed5d25e2a8fba82122b47818fba248ce 10.144.62.3:30003 slave 20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 0 1478638078833 5 connected
20be3e69195744aa379124d19a836650c72c23ba 10.144.62.3:30001 master,fail? - 1478638034799 1478638031628 5 connected 0-16383
```

And the `master,fail` state will not change no matter how long I wait

cluster info after service is stopped

```
cluster_state:fail

cluster_slots_assigned:16384

cluster_slots_ok:0

cluster_slots_pfail:16384

cluster_slots_fail:0

cluster_known_nodes:4

cluster_size:1

cluster_current_epoch:5

cluster_my_epoch:5

cluster_stats_messages_sent:1075189
```

cluster_stats_messages_received:930887

Comment: Do you want to setup a [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) with 4 nodes? Or just a single Redis instance with 3 slaves? It seems that you want the latter, however, you're setting up the former.

Comment: Could you do me a couple of things: #1 could we check you redis.conf file to see the slave-priority? #2 How do you kill your master node? #3 In redis-cli, what is the output for: CLUSTER INFO and CLUSTER NODES?

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, redis cluster will not work with less than 3 masters.

Take a look at this note on [redis cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-and-using-a-redis-cluster):

> Note that the minimal cluster that works as expected requires to
>   contain at least three master nodes. For your first tests it is
>   strongly suggested to start a six nodes cluster with three masters and
>   three slaves.

Comment: I did a fresh install with 3 masters and 3 slaves and the nodes responded just like how I wanted. Besides the cluster tutorial that suggests it is there any other documentation stating, something along the lines cluster failover will not work with less than X masters?

Comment: No, I didn't find any other official documentation stating that minimum.

Comment: If in 2 days no one can find that documentation, I will give you the bounty.

Comment: ok :). These two SO questions are related: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773968/minimum-amount-of-nodes-in-redis-cluster) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343449/cluster-failover).

Comment: forgot that I asked that question earlier

Comment: sadly they didnt answer my question, I dont want to chalk this up to just do it this way. But it looks that way

Comment: Try asking in [freenode #redis channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=redis)

Answer (score 0):

**Redis cluster needs a minimum of 3 master nodes without that it will not work.**

Adding slaves depends on the user but you can not move further without 3 master nodes.
And for setting up a cluster in windows you can follow the below-mentioned link I had tested the same.

[Redis cluster setup guide](https://dingyuliang.me/redis-3-2-create-cluster-windows/)